# Accessing Datasheet caption in Access 2007 with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

For some reason the text from the associated table's field description auto-populated the datasheet caption property on my form instead of the status bar text property. I want update the status bar text with this value. I am not sure how to reference the datasheet caption in design mode and run the following code:

Suggestions?

```
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In [Forms]![frmInventory].Controls
    Select Case ctl.ControlType
        Case acCommandButton, acCheckBox, acTextBox, acListBox, acComboBox, acToggleButton
        ctl.StatusBarText = ctl.Properties("DataSheetCaption")
    End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

At the table level, the datasheet caption is `.Properties("Caption")` in the DAO.Field object. (It may not exist if no custom caption was defined for that field.)

That property is not directly copied to a data control on a form. That is, a Text Box control will not have the caption in `.Properties("Caption")`. Instead, the caption is in the `.Caption` of the *Label* that is attached to the Text Box control.

So, if you want to copy the Datasheet Caption of the Field to the Status Bar Text of the Control you might have to

- get the name of the Field from the `.ControlSource` of the control,
- look up the Field in the `Fields` collection of the `TableDef` object, and
- pull the caption from the `.Properties("Caption")` property (if it exists) of the Field object.